# How to restore data with PostgreSQL's "pg_restore" and zero downtime?

Tags: postgresql, backup, psql, pg-restore

I try to restore a large table

`pg_restore.exe -U postgres -d db_name --clean --if-exists --single-transaction F:\Backups\PostgreSQL\data.dump.gz`

So I have a read lock for a few minutes. How to restore data with zero downtime for reading? I need only reading.

Comment: --clean means the table gets dropped and recreated.  What are the readers supposed to be reading?

Comment: Which is also where the lock comes in. [Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) ```ACCESS EXCLUSIVE``` "Acquired by the DROP TABLE, ..." [...]  "Only an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock blocks a SELECT (without FOR UPDATE/SHARE) statement." So you are going to have to tell us what is more import, getting rid of the read locks or the ```DROP/CREATE``` cycle?

Comment: The process of restoring data is by definition admitting the database, or at least the specific table,  is currently in an invalid/inaccurate state. Any select allowed then is subject to returning invalid/inaccurate results. That is worse than waiting or no results at all.  Your best approach is to inform your users (broadcast message or so), and proceed with restoration **with locks** in place.

Comment: @jjanes I also use `--single-transaction`, so I suppose the old data should still exist and I wanna read that.

Comment: Now I try a dirty way: restore table into another schema in this database, then `DROP` old table and `ALTER TABLE` new table `SET SCHEMA public`. In this way I have a zero downtime... But I'm still looking for more clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to not do the --clean and instead do --data-only, but then do a `DELETE from tablename` inside the same transaction, before the COPY.  I don't think there is a way to make pg_restore do this for you, but you could dump the output of pg_restore to a file and edit it, or use something like sed or perl to inject the DELETE.

This should work for table names which don't need to be quoted, and assuming none of the data being copied has first column which starts with 'COPY ':

```
pg_restore --data-only --single-transaction dmp.dmp -f -| perl -pe 's/^COPY ([\w.]+)/delete from $1; copy $1/' | psql -U postgres -d db_name
```

However, your schema changing method doesn't seem so dirty to me.  It still requires a momentary access exclusive lock, so it isn't really zero downtime, but it might be unnoticable downtime if it can acquire said lock quickly enough.